# SQL Script execution against the database

Tags: .net, vb.net

How to execute SQL scripts in vb.net other than by using SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT OBJECTS,splitting scripts with GO separator and then executing, via installer.Is there any methods other than these 3??

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use smo , as it is the best method for executing sql scripts?

Comment: .NET framework 4.0 supports SMO,as I am using framework 3.5  I can't use SMO.